# resize table columns to fit width

Tags: html, css, jhipster

I have a JHipster table into which I want to add vertical scroll. I tried this:

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="max-height: 800px;">
   <table class="table">
      <thead style="display:table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th class="hand">
               Pair                    
            </th>
            <th class="hand">
              Level 
            </th>
            <th class="hand">
               Spread                     
            </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="display:block; max-height: 300px; width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">             
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>267</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>silver</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

I want to have scroll only for table rows, not for head.
I tried to implement this using `display:block;` but the rows are too shrinked. Is it possible to resize the table rows to fill the entire width? Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I slightly edited your code stripping off the styles from the html and introducing a set of css rules.

I added some rows to better show the behaviour of the vertical scrollbar.

- tr: they all use `display: table;`
- tbody: has instead `display: block;` and `overflow: auto` to show scrollbars on table contents
- the table cells size are obtained with `table-layout: fixed`

the css rules apply to table elements having the `customtable` class

```css
/* styles tbody as having a fixed height and vertical scrollbar */
table.customtable tbody{
  display: block;
  /*arbitrary height to force the vertical scrollbar*/
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* styles table rows as taking 100% width and spreading cells width equally */
table.customtable tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

/* just to show off the table and cell borders */
table.customtable, table.customtable tr td {
    border: solid 1px lightgray;
}

table.othertable {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">

   <table class="customtable">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th class="hand">
               Pair                    
            </th>
            <th class="hand">
              Level 
            </th>
            <th class="hand">
               Spread                     
            </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>             
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>267</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>silver</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   
   <table class="othertable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Head1</th>    
        <th>Head2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Field1</td>
        <td>Field2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   
</div>
```

Comment: I have a small request. I have two tables into the page so I need to se this css code only for one table. How I can apply it for only one table?

Comment: I made the css rules more specific only on tables having the class customtable

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="max-height: 800px;">
   <table class="table" style="display:table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th class="hand">
               Pair                    
            </th>
            <th class="hand">
              Level 
            </th>
            <th class="hand">
               Spread                     
            </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>             
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>267</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>silver</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-cy="entityTable">
            <td>268</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>gold</td>
            <td>6</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```